# Is it apikorises to believe animals (not humans) evolved?

Tags: history, hashkafah-philosophy, heresy

Is it apikorises to believe such a thing? On the surface it makes sense, but evolutionism seems to greatly contradict with the Torah’s calendar in some ways.

Comment: Evolved from what?